# Qt + VTK + MAC version based compilation and execution

Tags: c++, qt, macos, vtk

I have successfully Built and compiled VTK with Qt on Mac osx 10.6.7. Then according to the requirements I changed configuration in CMAKE so that the target version is 10.5. I compiled VTK with Qt again and it was successful, with cones tutorials examples running. But whenever i compile my own application which is built using QVTK Widget i got this error

> "Check with the developer to make sure
>   Application works with this version of MacOS
>   X. You may need to reinstall the
>   application ..."

Following is my CMAKE Configuration

```
BUILD_EXAMPLES                checked
BUILD_SHARED_LIBS             checked
CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES       x86_64
CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET   10.5
CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT             /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk
VTK_USE_COCOA                 checked
VTK_USE_CARBON                unchecked
VTK_USE_QT                    checked
VTK_USE_QVT_QTOPENGL          checked
```

I have also ran following command on the terminal

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5
```

Every thing in my application compiles with both QtCreator and XCode but does not execute by giving the error as mentioned above.

In the above if i change everything from 10.5 to 10.6 everything start working. But according to requirement i need to have it compatible with 10.5.

Can someone please let me know is there anything else i need to do? Am i missing something here?

Regards,
Rashid

Comment: Didn't realize how old this question is, but we need the full crash log rather than just the dialog the Finder is showing you. Have you tried setting the `CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT` to the MacOSX10.6.sdk and the deployment target to 10.5 (this should be able to produce the desired result)?

Comment: Hi, Yeh i did. But i left it for later. Will update my questions once back over it.